# NodeJs Dev Automation on Windows

Tags: json, node.js, windows, bash

I am trying to automate my testing using NodeJs on *Windows*. I am new to this and I just learnt that I can run from the package.json file, in the scripts node some custom commands.

So I added the following to package.json:

```
"scripts": {
"prestart": "grunt",
"start": "node app",
"predev": "grunt",
"dev": "\"C:\\Program^ Files^ ^^^(x86^^^)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\" http://localhost:3000 & node-dev app & grunt watch"}
```

I am trying to launch chrome directly when I run **npm run dev**. When I try this I always get "*The system cannot find the path specified.*". I tried the path without the escape characters and it worked. I tried also a couple of escape character combinations (using quotes, spaces, etc.).

I know that I can do this easily by changing the location of chrome.exe. However, I wanted to learn how to solve this issue.

Comment: Just use `start http://localhost:3000` to open in your defalut browser, or `start chrome http://localhost:3000` if its not your default one.

Comment: Works Well! Thank you @dNitro